# How do i fix my class code 'int' object error?

Tags: python, class, object, methods

```
class Rbox:
    """ Defining a class """
    def __init__(self,num_parts=100):
        self.num_parts=num_parts
        self.list_particles=[0]*num_parts    
    def get_left_count(self):
        print("the number of particles on the left: "+str(self.list_particles.count(0)))
        return self.list_particles.count(0)      
    def get_right_count(self):
        print("The number of particles on the right is: "+str(self.list_particles.count(1)))
        return(self.list_particles.count(1))
    def run_sim(self,time=1000):
        for i in range(time):
            var=int(random.random())*(self.num_parts)
            if self.list_particles[var]==0:
                self.list_particles[var]=1
            if self.list_particles[var]==1:
                self.list_particles[var]=0
```

I'm trying to run the line `Rbox.run_sim(10)` in order to run a process that moves particles from a left hand box to a right hand box through a random process. But I keep getting the error `'int' object has no attribute 'num_parts'`. I'm not sure what to do to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have not initialised the class. Try

```
rbox = Rbox()
rbox.run_sim(10)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had done that before, but it's working now!